# I'm getting an inflate exception on a constraint layout and i don't know why

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I am receiving an InflateException with my messaging app. I am trying to have the messages that the users sent are aligned to the right and the messages received are aligned to the left. I used [this tutorial](https://blog.sendbird.com/android-chat-tutorial-building-a-messaging-ui) as a guide, but I am not sure why I am receiving it and would really appreciate any help.

I have tried updating Gradle to 4.3.0, but that gave me a different error.

activity_subject_group_page.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/txtUsernameAdminStudentPage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SubjectGroupPage">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvMessagesSubjectGroupPage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayoutMessageInput"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

list_item_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_message_body"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxWidth="240dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_message_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text_message_body"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/text_message_body" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

list_item_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_message_name"
    android:layout_width="157dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_message_body"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:maxWidth="240dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_message_name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_message_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text_message_body"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/text_message_body" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MessageObj.java

```
public class MessageObj {
private String message;
private String sender;
private String senderName;
private Timestamp timesent;
private boolean isCurrentUser;

public MessageObj() {}

public MessageObj(String message, String sender, String senderName, 
Timestamp timesent, boolean isCurrentUser) {
    this.message = message;
    this.sender = sender;
    this.senderName = senderName;
    this.timesent = timesent;
    this.isCurrentUser = isCurrentUser;
}

public String getMessage() { return message; }

public String getSender() { return sender; }

public String getSenderName() { return senderName; }

public Timestamp getTimesent() { return timesent; }

public boolean getIsCurrentUser() { return isCurrentUser; }
}
```

SentMessageHolder.java

```
public class SentMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView messageText, timeText, nameText;

SentMessageHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    messageText = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
    timeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
    nameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_name);
}

void bind(MessageObj message) {
    messageText.setText(message.getMessage());
    timeText.setText("" + message.getTimesent());
}
}
```

ReceivedMessageHolder.java

```
public class ReceivedMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView messageText, timeText, nameText;

ReceivedMessageHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    messageText = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
    timeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
    nameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_name);
}

void bind(MessageObj message) {
    messageText.setText(message.getMessage());
    timeText.setText("" + message.getTimesent());
    nameText.setText(message.getSenderName());
}
}
```

MessageListAdapter.java

```
public class MessageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2;

private Context mContext;
private List<MessageObj> mMessageList;

public MessageListAdapter(Context context, List<MessageObj> messageList) 
{
    mContext = context;
    mMessageList = messageList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMessageList.size();
}

// Determines the appropriate ViewType according to the sender of the message.
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (mMessageList.get(position).getSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
        // If the current user is the sender of the message
        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;
    } else {
        // If some other user sent the message
        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
    }
}

// Inflates the appropriate layout according to the ViewType.
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;

    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_right, parent, false);
        return new SentMessageHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_left, parent, false);
        return new ReceivedMessageHolder(view);
    }

    return null;
}

// Passes the message object to a ViewHolder so that the contents can be bound to UI.
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MessageObj message = (MessageObj) mMessageList.get(position);

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT:
            ((SentMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
            ((ReceivedMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
    }
}

private class SentMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView messageText, timeText;

    SentMessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        messageText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
        timeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
    }

    void bind(MessageObj message) {
        messageText.setText(message.getMessage());

        // Format the stored timestamp into a readable String using method.
        timeText.setText("" + message.getTimesent());
    }
}

private class ReceivedMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView messageText, timeText, nameText;

    ReceivedMessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        messageText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
        timeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
        nameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_name);
    }

    void bind(MessageObj message) {
        messageText.setText(message.getMessage());

        // Format the stored timestamp into a readable String using method.
        timeText.setText("" + message.getTimesent());

        nameText.setText(message.getSenderName());
    }
}
}
```

SubjectGroupPage.java

```
public class SubjectGroupPage extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTextMessage;
private static final String TAG = "SubjectGroupPage.java";
private final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
private final FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
private RecyclerView mMessageRecycler;
private MessageListAdapter mMessageAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subject_group_page);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    mTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.message);
    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String studentName = intent.getStringExtra("studentName");

    BottomNavigationItemView navigationHome = (BottomNavigationItemView) findViewById(R.id.navigationHome);
    BottomNavigationItemView navigationNotifications = (BottomNavigationItemView) findViewById(R.id.navigationNotifications);
    final RecyclerView rvMessagesSubjectGroupPage = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvMessagesSubjectGroupPage);

    mMessageRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvMessagesSubjectGroupPage);
    mMessageRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    navigationHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), StudentInfoPage.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    navigationNotifications.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), SubjectGroupPage.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btnSubjectInfoSubjectGroupPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), SubjectInfoPage.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btnSendMessageSubjectGroupPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String message = edtMessageInputSubjectGroupPage.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message, studentName);
            edtMessageInputSubjectGroupPage.setText("");

        }
    });

    rvMessagesSubjectGroupPage.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, true));
    final ArrayList<MessageObj> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<MessageObj> messagesAdap = readMessages(rvMessagesSubjectGroupPage, messages);
    mMessageAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(this, messagesAdap);
    rvMessagesSubjectGroupPage.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

}

public ArrayList<MessageObj> readMessages(final RecyclerView rv, final ArrayList<MessageObj> messages) {

    db.collection("messagesIT")
            .orderBy("Timesent", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            String message = document.getString("Message");
                            String senderName = document.getString("SenderName");
                            String sender = document.getString("Sender");
                            Timestamp timesent = document.getTimestamp("Timesent");
                            MessageObj mess;

                            sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                            if (currentUser.getUid().equals(sender)) {
                                mess = new MessageObj(message, sender, senderName, timesent, true);
                                editor.putBoolean("isCurrentUser", true);
                                editor.commit();
                            } else {
                                mess = new MessageObj(message, sender, senderName, timesent, false);
                                editor.putBoolean("isCurrentUser", false);
                                editor.commit();
                            }
                            messages.add(mess);
                            Log.d(TAG, "mmmmm: " + mess.getMessage());
                            Log.d(TAG, "sssss: " + mess.getSender());
                            Log.d(TAG, "ttttt:" + mess.getTimesent());
                            showToast("b");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            showToast("There has been an error, please try again later.");
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e);

        }
    });
    return messages;
}

public void sendMessage(String msg, String studentName) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Message Details
    Map<String, Object> messageMap = new HashMap<>();
    messageMap.put("Message", msg);
    messageMap.put("Timesent", new Timestamp(new Date()));
    messageMap.put("Sender", currentUser.getUid());
    messageMap.put("SenderName", studentName);

    // Add a new document with a generated ID with user details
    db.collection("messagesIT")
            .add(messageMap)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sending message was a success");
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "There was an error sending the message");
        }
    });

}

}
```

Project-level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app-level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "oxley.it.collectivelearning"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
}
```

Error

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: oxley.it.collectivelearning, PID: 18952
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:797)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:737)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at oxley.it.collectivelearning.MessageListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MessageListAdapter.java:53)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22468)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at 



 androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22468)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6794)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    E/AndroidRuntime: at 
 androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22468)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6794)
        at 
androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:401)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22468)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6794)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22468)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6794)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22468)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6794)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:807)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2833)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1771)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2043)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1659)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7596)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:732)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:664)
        at 
 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:187)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7025)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at 
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:514)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex 
    location /data/app/oxley.it.collectivelearning-rBOYhtuR1Jj1cYDk7OIxvg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at 
 com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at 
 com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at 
    android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at 
    android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:35)
        at 
    android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:743)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:777)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1017)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2390)
        at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6069)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1861)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                ... 5 more
```

Comment: Just add logcat here

Comment: @Kabir Sorry, just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace in **list_item_left.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

with

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed that and both list XML files and it fixed the error.